# flask+react website using App Engine, url not found

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, flask, yaml, app.yaml

A simple flask+ react website that i have deployed to App Engine works fine locally.
When I serve main.py locally and go to /hello it returns "hello world" as it should. However when deployed to app engine and using the provided URL with /hello it returns "The requested URL /hello was not found on this server."

below is main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="./build/static", template_folder="./build")
 @app.route("/")
 def index():
     return render_template("index.html")
@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

here's my app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
- url: /(.*)
  script: auto
```

```
project_root/
build/
   static/
   index.html
app.yaml
main.py
```

It also returns index.html fine on app engine when entering [provided-url].com/

Answer (score 1):

Your url handlers in app.yaml are short-circuiting.  The first `/` matches, and it never gets to the 2nd `/` handler.  I think you want something like:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: build/static/
- url: /(.*)
  script: auto
```

then let your Flask handlers do all the work.  Then, send all your calls to static files to `/static/somefile.jpg` etc.

**EDIT:** If you want to make your life easier, don't serve `index.html` as a static file.  Serve it from main.py, as you have that set up.  All of your React urls get handled in main.py, and all separately render `index.html`.  All of your React routing and components get called from inside `index.html`. Your API calls get handled in main.py as well.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    template_context = {
        'msg'      : "you are on my home page",
    }
    return render_template("index.html", **template_context)

@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    template_context = {
        'msg'      : "this is your user profile",
    }
    return render_template("index.html", **template_context)

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

**EDIT #2:** If you insist on serving index.html as a static file, you could set up your app.yaml like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /static
  static_dir: build/static/
- url: /(.*)
  script: auto
```

and you would delete the `@app.route("/")` handler from main.py, as it will never get there.

Comment: This is a react application. I want it to serve index.html and let react to take care of its routes. But also be able to respond to API calls like /hello. So the first two handlers are for sending index.html when user visits the home page.

Comment: But / doesn't match everything. My app.yaml is from google docs. Your solution returns server error 500. `The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.` When I run my code locally it runs fine.

Comment: Are you talking about the url handlers in app.yaml or main.py? Link to the docs you copied from would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So after messing around with my code for days the  problem was with the handlers. With `runtime:python37` you shouldn’t use the handlers. Not sure why but when I removed the handlers from app.yaml it all worked.

Comment: If the issue persists or any other issues related to Google Cloud Services, I would like to direct you to [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). The Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. More in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker#about_issue_tracker).